# Is there a way to force to games join specific server only? or create custom routes?

Tags: networking, windows-10

So i play this China game called Call of Duty: Online, I live in singapore but weirdly i have high ping in that game... but when i use accelerator "Netease UU" my ping from 300-200 to 90-120. 
Now they decided to start charging after they done testing with servers for years.

I want to force my game to connect to "43.230.90.102"

**Network Activity:**

Without Netease UU: 
[image: A lot of servers]

With Netease UU:
[image: Only 1 Server]

I can ping "43.230.90.102" even without opening Netease UU.

Please tell me if it's possible!

Comment: Ok, so what is 43.230.90.102? I think you want to know how to fake your computer so that your computer thinks it's connected to a different country? You'd have to use a proxy server. You can purchase this proxy, or you can find freey proxy servers. Search "proxy server" or "free proxy servers". I don't want to be specific because I think it's out of scope, but that will get you started in a way of thinking about your problem.

Comment: no this game is not banned in my country. i don't need to hide, i just want force my game to connect 43.230.90.102

Comment: You seem to know exactly what you are doing. So why ask then? You didn't even bother to tell me what that ip is. I'm not going to ping that ip address because it has nothing to do with me, so that's why I'm asking you.

Comment: I'm trying to ask people on how to force my game to connect that server directly. I don't know how to do that,

Comment: If they are charging then most likely you won't be able to connect to the server you want to. It's very easy to block access to IP's and so asking people to Log On is a way of authenticating access,and in authentication practices they are probably grabbing your IP address that is matched against a list of IP's (you) that have granted access to certain servers. It's your credentials so to speak. If there is a way to FORCE access to a specific IP that would otherwise block you, then that would be a HACK and it would have to use a 3rd party hack-software.

Comment: Your “accelerator” caused the software to believe itself at a different location, where it would connect to different servers. You cannot emulate this effect without a VPN. Either you pay for that accelerator or a “real” VPN provider.

Comment: i see. can i block all servers on windows firewall until they put me on low ping server?

Comment: No, you cannot. In the first place, you don’t even know its address. 43.230.90.102 is most likely just the tunnel endpoint of your accelerator. CoD Online most likely still uses P2P anyway.